# Collision fires only for the last DIV

Tags: javascript, dom, collision-detection, collision

I'm trying to trigger some events when one DOM element collide with another. A have a bunch of objects, how many I don't know, so I take them like `querySelectorAll` and then I'm trying to loop them via `foreach`. Everything works fine except - the even fires only for the last element. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Codepen — https://codepen.io/PavelLaptev/pen/ZEQPaRa

```js
const isCollide = (a, b) => {
  var x1 = a.offsetLeft;
  var y1 = a.offsetTop;
  var h1 = a.clientHeight;
  var w1 = a.clientWidth;
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = b.offsetLeft;
  var y2 = b.offsetTop;
  var h2 = b.clientHeight;
  var w2 = b.clientWidth;
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;

  return true;
};

const interactElements = document.querySelectorAll(".object");
const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

console.log(interactElements);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let cursorPos = {
        x: e.x - 20 / 2,
        y: e.y - 20 / 2,
    };

    cursor.style.top = `${cursorPos.y}px`;
    cursor.style.left = `${cursorPos.x}px`;
    
    interactElements.forEach((item) => {
        if (isCollide(cursor, item)) {
            cursor.style.background = "blue";
        } else {
            cursor.style.background = "red";
        }
    });
})
```

```css
.objects {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.object {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 20px;
}

#cursor {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
<div class="objects">
  <div class="object"></div>
  <div class="object"></div>
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The forEach loop causes this; assuming the collision is between cursor and object #1, the negative test for object #2 and #3 will turn the color back to red. You need to use `cursor.style.background = Array.from(interactElements).some(item => isCollide(cursor, item)) ? "blue" : "red";`

Comment: just curious to know, why are you doing it in Javascript? this functionality could have been achieved using CSS.

Comment: ForEach loop won't wait till the function returns. That's what causing the issue.

Comment: @PraveenMP interesting! Do you have any examples with described behavior using CSS?

Comment: Praveen is talking about a `:hover` rule but if you want to do more than just change the color, that's not a sufficient alternative.

Comment: @ChrisG exactly. I also thought about tracking mouseover on the element, but I also need to achieve the different hit area. Trying different variations right now. But my question above didn't let me sleep peacefully :-) thanks

Comment: As @ChrisG mentioned, if you just want to change the color go with CSS, but if you want achieve something else go with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
interactElements.forEach((item) => {
    if (isCollide(cursor, item)) {
        cursor.style.background = "blue";
    } else {
        cursor.style.background = "red";
    }
});
```

to:

```
 cursor.style.background = Array.from(interactElements).some((item) => isCollide(cursor, item)) ? 'blue' : 'red'
```

```js
const isCollide = (a, b) => {
  var x1 = a.offsetLeft;
  var y1 = a.offsetTop;
  var h1 = a.clientHeight;
  var w1 = a.clientWidth;
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = b.offsetLeft;
  var y2 = b.offsetTop;
  var h2 = b.clientHeight;
  var w2 = b.clientWidth;
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;

  return true;
};

const interactElements = document.querySelectorAll(".object");
const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

console.log(interactElements);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let cursorPos = {
        x: e.x - 20 / 2,
        y: e.y - 20 / 2,
    };

    cursor.style.top = `${cursorPos.y}px`;
    cursor.style.left = `${cursorPos.x}px`;
    cursor.style.background = Array.from(interactElements).some((item) => isCollide(cursor, item)) ? 'blue' : 'red'
})
```

```css
.objects {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.object {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 20px;
}

#cursor {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
<div class="objects">
  <div class="object"></div>
  <div class="object"></div>
  <div class="object"></div>
</div>
```